# Satellizer Twitter (oAuth 1.0a) popup does not close

Tags: twitter, oauth, satellizer

I'm having a good time with Satellizer, except in one case - the Twitter oAuth 1.0a flow. The popup does not close after successfully authenticating a user.

My configuration is;

```
    $authProvider.twitter({
        url: '<my server endpoint to get request token (POST)>',
        redirectUri: '<my server endpoint to perform oAuth login (GET)>'
    });
```

I have set the callback URI for my Twitter app to be the same as `redirectUri` (and I also pass it when getting a request token from Twitter).

The flow that I see is this (basically, I get to Step 10 in the oAuth 1.0 flow and then the popup does not close):

- User clicks the "Sign in with Twitter" button
- The popup appears and an empty POST call is made - my server returns the request token
- The user clicks "Authorize Application"
- My server receives a `GET` request for the oAuth login (not a `POST` as the documentation says I should)
- My server correctly authenticates and returns the Bearer token.

And then nothing - it all stops. I suspect because I am responding to a `GET` not a `POST` but I can't figure out what is causing the `GET`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Ben

Comment: So I have made some progress - I can now get the popup to close. The problem (I think) was that I was setting the redirect URI to a valid endpoint (which then gets invoked as a `GET`). When you don't do that (i.e.: set the `redirectUri` to be something that bounces, I get a (second) POST call to the `auth/provider` method.

I don't get any parameters on that secondary call, but I am getting closer I think.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies everyone - this is my fault. Per my comment above, once I set the `redirectUri` properly and used just the `/auth/provider` method it all worked.

Quite simply, on the second call the parameters come through (correctly) in the body. Once I realised that, extracted them, authenticated, and then returned, it all worked like a charm.